# How can I save a value from MySQL database into a .txt file when a download button is clicked?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am just getting started with `MySQL` and `PHP`, I created a table "Joke" in my database and I showed the data in my PHP server side with this code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT joketext FROM joke');  


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
  $jokes[] = $row['joketext'];  
}  

include 'jokes.html.php';
```

And HTML code:

```
<p>Here are all the jokes in the database:</p>  
    <?php foreach ($jokes as $joke): ?>  
      <blockquote><p>  
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($joke, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>  
      </p></blockquote>  
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

That's worked for me, but now I want to add a button "download" beside each joke to download it in `.txt` file.

Comment: Since the joke is already part of the page you could use client-side javascript to make it downloadable. See: [How to create a file and generate a download with Javascript in the Browser (without a server)](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the HTML/PHP portion of your page to include a simple hyperlink like this:

```
<p>Here are all the jokes in the database:</p>  
<?php foreach ($jokes as $id => $joke): ?>  
  <blockquote>
      <p>  
        <?php 
            echo htmlspecialchars($joke, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        ?>
      </p>
      <a class='download' href='#' title='Download the joke'>Download</a>
  </blockquote>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then copy the javascript from below to your page you should find that you are able to download the jokes as desired. If you copy all of the code below you should find that it will run in your browser ok.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Download a joke</title>
        <script>
            /*
                wait for the DOM to load and then set event listeners
                on the new hyperlinks
            */
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
                /*
                    Query the DOM for ALL hyperlinks of class `download`
                    and assign an event handler for click events
                */
                document.querySelectorAll('a.download').forEach( function(a){
                    a.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ){
                        /*
                            prevent the default action for this hyperlink
                        */
                        event.preventDefault();

                        /*
                            The Joke is located in the previous
                            DOM node - P
                        */
                        let p=this.previousElementSibling;

                        /*
                            create a BLOB object to store the joke text
                        */
                        let blob=new Blob([ p.innerText ],{type: 'text/plain'});


                        /*
                            function to send the file - jiggery pokery
                        */
                        const sendfile=function( blob, name ){
                            let url=URL.createObjectURL( blob );
                            let lnk=document.createElement('a');
                            let evt=new MouseEvent('click',{
                                bubbles:true,
                                cancelable:true,
                                view:window
                            });
                            p.appendChild( lnk );
                            lnk.href=url;
                            lnk.download=name;
                            lnk.dispatchEvent( evt );
                            p.removeChild( lnk );
                        }


                        sendfile.call( this, blob, 'joke.txt' );
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- EXAMPLE DATA -->
        <blockquote>
            <p>  
                This is the joke - not very funny though is it?
            </p>
            <a class='download' href='#' title='Download the joke'>Download</a>
        </blockquote>

        <blockquote>
            <p>  
                This is another joke - or what passes for a joke!
            </p>
            <a class='download' href='#' title='Download the joke'>Download</a>
        </blockquote>

        <blockquote>
            <p>  
                This is probably not the best joke in the World.
            </p>
            <a class='download' href='#' title='Download the joke'>Download</a>
        </blockquote>

        <blockquote>
            <p>  
                A woman gets on a bus with her baby. The bus driver says: 'Ugh, that's the ugliest 
                baby I've ever seen!' The woman walks to the rear of the bus and sits down, fuming. 
                She says to a man next to her: 'The driver just insulted me!' The man says: 'You go 
                up there and tell him off. Go on, I'll hold your monkey for you.
            </p>
            <a class='download' href='#' title='Download the joke'>Download</a>
        </blockquote>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you !! That's worked ,But does this code work only if the the previous DOM node  is  `<p>` ? Becouse i tried it with `Textarea` but it does not worked (the `joke.txt` was empty)

Comment: you would need to modify the code for use with an `INPUT` element.  A `paragraph` element has an innerHTML/innerText but an INPUT element such as a textarea has a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can `implode()` the `$jokes` array:

```
$all_jokes = implode("\n", $jokes);
file_put_contents("all_jokes.txt", $all_jokes);
```

and in your html page:

```
<a href="all_jokes.txt">Download all</a>
```

references here:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_put_contents.asp
https://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Thanks @andreah but i want to download each joke in `joke.txt` file